# Flutter Image from Arabic URL

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-image, arabic-support

I try:

```
Image.network("http://ar.latifaonline.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/ألبوم-لطيفة-2022.png"),
```

but that does not work because Arabic characters convert to become :

```
"http://ar.latifaonline.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/%D8%A3%D9%84%D8%A8%D9%88%D9%85-%D9%84%D8%B7%D9%8A%D9%81%D8%A9-2022.png"
```

and that does not give any image but returns this error:

> Exception has occurred.
> HttpException (HttpException: Connection closed before full header was received, uri = http://ar.latifaonline.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/%D8%A3%D9%84%D8%A8%D9%88%D9%85-%D9%84%D8%B7%D9%8A%D9%81%D8%A9-2022.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get this error is not because of the Arabic characters, is because of `http`, change it to `https` and it will work.

if you don't have access to your backend code try this:

```
String yourUrl =
        "http://ar.latifaonline.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/ألبوم-لطيفة-2022.png";

yourUrl = yourUrl.replaceFirst('http://', "https://");

Image.network(yourUrl)
```